# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I try to use the quickstart of sign-in with Microsoft but when I try to log an error appear:

[image: Error]

in my config file i have this parameters:

[image: config file]

and in the app config i have this paramter:

[image: redirect url]

i dont know what is happening :(

Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Redirect_Path` should be same with azure portal `Redirect URIs`.

[image]

> **Note:** Protocol matters. AAD will treat `http://localhost/logfinal/` and `https://localhost/logfinal/` as
> different reply URLs. If you are still having an issue after following
> the steps above, check that the configured reply URL matches the
> protocol you're actually using.

Hope this would help. Additionally, please refer to [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/troubleshooting/auth/aadauth-replyurls) for more details.

Comment: "Note: Port 5000 is not recommended by Microsoft. You should better to change the port from 5000 to the effective one."? Citation needed.

Comment: @RayLuo Done, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry but, by "citation needed", I did NOT mean just to add a quoting visual effect. I mean, it would better to leave an official document which says "port 5000 is not recommended". I cannot find it from the official document. Are you sure you read such statement from Microsoft doc?

Comment: Ah, I see! its hard for me to remember that one as its bit late since I have answered, I am trying to update with specific link.

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of a technological reason to recommend against port 5000. If your effective port happens to be 5000, then you should just go for it.

Comment: I have updated the answer with removing that part, I would update that once I get the reference again. When I write code I and god knows after a long time only god knows! I depend mostly on my comment and docs I share with the content writing team.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. For me, the issue was that I was navigating to url that flask provides when it starts: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login` rather than `http://localhost:5000/login` which is the url that the app registration is looking for.

Comment: Could you please share the settings too?

Comment: @MuratDemir what settings are you looking for?